# RESTful web service returns 500 server error in Chrome console while working perfectly on website

Tags: rest, shopify, webservice-client, google-chrome-console

We have a strange situation with our website
https://www.withclarity.com/collections/natural-diamonds?shape=Round
We are fetching the diamond data in above shopify website through an  external web service hosted on

https://vportalwithclarity.com/fetchdirectdiamond/ through Post Method

Here is the sample of the request body

But the response body in the chrome console (XHR network request) in **500 server error

But it all works fine on the website

What could be the issue

expected to show full response in the  chrome console instead of 500 server error